# Há uma forma de centralizar a tela criada em python ( pyqt ) para qualquer resolução?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Estou fazendo desenvolvimento de uma aplicação em python e qt, ou seja, pyqt5 e gostaria de saber se exite uma forma de sempre que que executar o display que criei centralizar na tela, eu vi que tem como fazer isso manualmente setando valores fixos para top e left por exemplo, mas eu gostaria que o display centralizasse na tela em qualquer resolução e gostaria de saber se isso exite e se possível como eu poderia fazer.

Obs: Sou iniciante tanto em python quanto qt.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar esse código no seu MainWindow:

```
self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- self.rect().center())
```

Pode tentar também o código abaixo:

```
mainWindow.resize(mainWindow.sizeHint().width,
        mainWindow.size().height() + content.sizeHint().height());
```

Logo após adicionar todos os elementos à tela principal.